# Why the WordPress Bengali Post Link is cut short?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, bengali

My website is [Mahtab.Online](https://mahtab.online/) It is designed in Bengali. My website's permalink setting is set to ***%category%/%postname%***

My post's title is "বাংলাদেশে বিভিন্ন রোগে মানুষের আক্রান্তের হার ও প্রতিকার".
So, the link should be "https://mahtab.online/স্বাস্থ্য/বাংলাদেশে-বিভিন্ন-রোগে-মানুষের-আক্রান্তের-হার-ও-প্রতিকার"
but the post link is shown "https://mahtab.online/স্বাস্থ্য/বাংলাদেশে-বিভিন্ন-রোগে-ম".

Why the link is cut short? How to make the link full?

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slug character limit by default can you check that fact?

Due to wp_posts table structure the length of post_name column (the column for slugs) is equal to 200 characters.

[described problems facts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53042/is-there-a-maximum-slug-length)

Comment: I have changed it to 500.
But nothing happeded.
https://i.postimg.cc/QdP0KbYp/postname.png